# Header and footer is not binding in word javascript api

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I am  working on a Word Add-in for one or our applications. Using this Word add-in, send saved Word templates from our application to Word.

If I use a template that is includes a header and footer, these do not show up in the Word document.

Here is the code:

```js
function setDocumentDataBase64(data) {
    Word.run(function (context) {
            // Create a proxy object for the document body.
            var body = context.document.body;
            //cleaning old context
            //body.clear();
            body.insertFileFromBase64(data, Word.InsertLocation.replace);
            return context.sync().then(function () {
                alert.success("Document inserted");
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
            if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Did you managed to resolve the issue? do you have any sample code that you could share? i have the same exact problem.

Comment: Yes i did.  gist.github.com/JuaneloJuanelo/61ee8983fc914592b618a9a392d15f44

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you mean by "binding" on this question (as "binding" is a very specific concept in Office.js). I am guessing that what you are trying to do is to insert a document containing header/footers via range.insertFileFromBase64  and you are not seeing the header and footers after the insertion, if that's the case its a by design issue, and the reason, we don't want to replace the header/footer of the current document. The goal of the method is to reuse chunks of documents, not replacing the entire document.

If you need to change the header, you need to do so manually.

You can explore the createDocument API (who actually opens a new document window) is in preview and might be what you need.

Hope this helps.
thanks!
Juan.

this is the sample code of getting the base64 of the current document:

```js
 function getFile(){
        Office.context.document.getFileAsync(Office.FileType.Compressed, { sliceSize: 4194304  /*64 KB*/ },
          function (result) {
              if (result.status == "succeeded") {
                  // If the getFileAsync call succeeded, then
                  // result.value will return a valid File Object.
                  var myFile = result.value;
                  var sliceCount = myFile.sliceCount;
                  var slicesReceived = 0, gotAllSlices = true, docdataSlices = [];
                  console.log("File size:" + myFile.size + " #Slices: " + sliceCount);

                  // Get the file slices.
                  getSliceAsync(myFile, 0, sliceCount, gotAllSlices, docdataSlices, slicesReceived);
              }
              else {
                  app.showNotification("Error:", result.error.message);
              }
          });

    
    
    }


    function getSliceAsync(file, nextSlice, sliceCount, gotAllSlices, docdataSlices, slicesReceived) {
        file.getSliceAsync(nextSlice, function (sliceResult) {
            if (sliceResult.status == "succeeded") {
                if (!gotAllSlices) { // Failed to get all slices, no need to continue.
                    return;
                }

                // Got one slice, store it in a temporary array.
                // (Or you can do something else, such as
                // send it to a third-party server.)
                docdataSlices[sliceResult.value.index] = sliceResult.value.data;
                if (++slicesReceived == sliceCount) {
                    // All slices have been received.
                    file.closeAsync();
                    onGotAllSlices(docdataSlices);
                }
                else {
                    getSliceAsync(file, ++nextSlice, sliceCount, gotAllSlices, docdataSlices, slicesReceived);
                }
            }
            else {
                gotAllSlices = false;
                file.closeAsync();
                console.log("getSliceAsync Error:", sliceResult.error.message);
            }
        });
    }

    function onGotAllSlices(docdataSlices) {
        var docdata = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < docdataSlices.length; i++) {
            docdata = docdata.concat(docdataSlices[i]);
        }
        var fileContent = new String();

        for (var j = 0; j < docdata.length; j++) {
            fileContent += String.fromCharCode(docdata[j]);
        }
       
 


        var mybase64 = window.btoa(fileContent);
        console.log("here is the base 64", mybase64);
        // Now all the file content is stored in 'fileContent' variable,
        // you can do something with it, such as print, fax...
    }
```

Comment: Yes i want to replace the header and footer as well in the current document.

Comment: And right now i am just able to replace the body only is there any way to replace the header and footer as well in same document.

Comment: Where i can found createDocument API if you have any link or any example that will be beneficial for us. Thanks Kapil

Comment: hello i am not able to find this api can you please help.

Comment: check out this sample (load it from script lab) https://gist.github.com/JuaneloJuanelo/61ee8983fc914592b618a9a392d15f44  shows how to insert a header in a document.

Comment: But in this example you are inserting header only but i am having complete document in base64string that is congaing header footer and body all the things combine and that i want to render in word document.

Comment: Unfortunately, headers and footers are not replaced using the insertfile method. So createDocument will be your only option see this answer with pointers to documentation and how to use it (note that it's in preview )https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40655463/context-application-is-undefined-when-using-wordapi-1-3

Comment: I have one more question while creating base64string of document i am getting the header but footer is missing when i am converting back that base64string to document.

Comment: how are you creating the base64?

Comment: I am using   Office.context.document.getFileAsync for getting conpressed slices of the document in bytes and that slices i am converting into base64string
    var docdata = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < docdataSlices.length; i++) {
            docdata = docdata.concat(docdataSlices[i]);
        }

        var fileContent = new String();
        for (var j = 0; j < docdata.length; j++) {
            fileContent += String.fromCharCode(docdata[j]);
        }
        var base64String = "";
        eval(fn)(base64String);

Comment: check out the example the i added to my answer. in the mybase64 variable i am dropping the base64 for a docx. When i restore it i do get the headers and footers of the file.